# Running a virtual GPU

Tags: virtual-machine, graphics-card, gpu, computer-building

So I just finished building my PC, and I decided to go for more RAM and a better CPU at the expense of not getting the best graphics card. And so my question is this: can you run a virtual graphics card that will take care of the more resource intensive graphics processes instead of the graphics card I already have. Essentially, in my openGL/graphics settings it would show up as an option for multiple GPUs or something like that. And, if this isn't possible, then is there at least some way to allocate a portion of my normal RAM to my graphics card (I have enough RAM that I can definitely spare some) If it helps, my graphics card is a Geforce GT 710, my CPU is a Ryzen Threadripper 1920x, and I have 32gb of DDR4 corsair vengeance RAM (Yes, I know that this is basically the definition of a performance bottleneck) But anyways if that is possible how would one go about doing that.

P.S. Also I have heard that doing this is just incredibly slow and not worth it. I figured since I normally have tons of extra RAM, and, In the task manager my CPU usage never goes above 10% I might be able to dedicate a large amount of that to running a virtual GPU. Would this make it worth it?

Thanks,
smcbot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you put a lawnmower engine in a Ferrari.

The only way to get better performance is get a better GPU. That one is the lowest of the low.
Getting the CPU to do the work of the GPU will be app-dependant; some games can do it to persuade them to work at bare minimum settings on poor computers. It may be labelled as 'hardware skinning' & is invariably slow & vastly lower quality.

Comment: Lol ok thx. I was planning on updating my graphics card anyways but I wanted to make sure I wasn't wasting a bunch of money when there was a free alternative.